# Change the size of the captcha image in yii

Tags: yii

I would like to change the size of the captcha image in yii. I know the width originally is set to 100. I would like to make it twice as big. I can't get anything to change with the following code.

```
<?php $this->widget('CCaptcha',array('buttonOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:200')));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the image size, then you should use `imageOptions` instead of `buttonOptions`, something like:

```
<?php $this->widget('CCaptcha', array('imageOptions' => array('style'=>'width:20%'))); ?>
```

Take a look at the [CCaptcha](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCaptcha) documentation.

Comment: Just a heads up, this stretches the image to the set size

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that naturally without setting a style for the image element. In `SiteController` you have `actions()` method that returns an array of options for `captcha` built-in action.

```
public function actions()
{
    return array(
        // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page
        'captcha'=>array(
            'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
            'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
            'width' => '..' // <- Set this to override a default width
        ),
```

And then render it without params:

```
<?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is solution via template
PHP:

```
        <?= $form->field($model, 'verifyCode')->widget(Captcha::className(), ['template' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3">{image}</div><div class="col-lg-6">{input}</div></div>']) ?>
```

JS:

```
    document.getElementById("reviews-verifycode-image").style.height = "100px";
```